# Running a while loop (to execute query) for a predefined number

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I want to run this query `10 times`:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO user_thoughts VALUES ('','message', '$date_of_msg','', '$name', 'yes')");
```

From my understanding, a for loop is required? But I do not understand how the query fits in the while loop, for example, this is what I have so far:

```
for($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO user_thoughts VALUES ('','message', '$date_of_msg','', '$name', 'yes')");
        break;
}
```

But the above generated 28 new rows for me, whereas I want the query to execute 10 times.

Comment: It seems pretty obvious that the above will execute the query exactly once, not 10 times and not 28. Therefore the answer seems to be "you are running this inside a loop".

Comment: `for` loop is not technically required. That depends on whether you need to dynamically use the `$i` value in your query. As for the` while` loop, see my answer below. I don't know what magic happened for that code to generate 28 rows for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why did you include a "break"? I think that's your problem. At the end of your first execution that "break" will bring your program out of that loop. Take out that "break" and your code will execute exactly 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 1;
while($i <= 10) {
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO user_thoughts VALUES ('','message', '$date_of_msg','', '$name', 'yes')");
 $i++;
}
```